# Nodelist - 'undefined: not bound to any nodes'

Tags: javascript, yui

What's wrong with this?

```
YUI().use('node', function (Y) 
{
  var doc = Y.one('#content');
  // alert(doc.getHTML());
  var nodes = new Y.NodeList(doc.getElementsByTagName('h1'));
  // Do something ...
});
```

doc.getHTML() shows the expected document with some level 1 headings. But nodes is always *'undefined: not bound to any nodes'*.

Thx for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'doc' is a Y.Node object, not a native DOM object, and so does not have a getElementsByTagName() method. In this case, I think you want:

```
var nodes = doc.all('h1');
```

Keep in mind that when manipulating the DOM with YUI, you are working with a facade object, a Y.Node or a Y.NodeList. Don't mix YUI method calls with native DOM method calls unless you are sure you know what you are doing.

Comment: Hey, this works. But I am confused: [Node class](http://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/api/classes/Node.html) There is a "getElementsByTagName" method.

Comment: Node's .getElementsByTagName returns a NodeList itself which is not an "acceptable" argument type to new Y.NodeList. So if doc is for sure a Y.Node you could have done just var nodes = doc.getElementsByName('h1') to get the NodeList, but Evan's answer is the better way to do it.